# Compound interest calculation on changing balance for data.table

Tags: r, data.table

I have a data.table which has a balance. The balance is based on deposits/withdrawals each period. Each period there is an interest rate that should be applied. However I am not able to compound the interest rate to the balances, basically applying the interest rate to the balance and then using the updated balance in the next period to calculate the new value.

```
Balance_t1 = (0 + Deposit_t1)*(1+Interest_t1)

Balance_t2 = (Balance_t1 + Deposit_t2)*(1+Interest_t2)

Balance_t3 = (Balance_t2 + Deposit_t3)*(1+Interest_t3)
```

I have the following `data.table`

```
dtCash <- data.table(
  Deposit = c(100, 100, -300, 0), 
  Balance = c(100, 200, -100, -100),
  Interest=c(0.1, 0.01, 0.2, 0.1)
)
```

The result would be:

```
dtCash <- data.table(
  Deposit = c(100, 100, -300, 0), 
  Balance = c(100, 200, -100, -100), 
  Interest=c(0.1, 0.01, 0.2, 0.1), 
  BalanceWithInterest = c(110, 212.1, -105.48, -116.028)
)
```

How do I update and reference the updated Balance column in every period?

Comment: There are packages available to do all sorts of financial calculations.  `FinCal` and `financial` are two such.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It seems like you're looking for a "cumulative sum and product," which I don't know of a way to do in R (other than, for instance, with @dynamo's for loop).

That being said, this can be done efficiently with a relatively simple Rcpp solution:

```
library(Rcpp)
getBalance <- cppFunction(
  "NumericVector getBalance(NumericVector deposit,
                            NumericVector interest) {
    NumericVector result(deposit.size());
    double prevResult = 0.0;
    for (int i=0; i < deposit.size(); ++i) {
      result[i] = (prevResult + deposit[i]) * (1.0 + interest[i]);
      prevResult = result[i];
    }
    return result;
  }")
Deposit <- c(100, 100, -300, 0)  
Interest <- c(0.1, 0.01, 0.2, 0.1)
getBalance(Deposit, Interest)
# [1]  110.000  212.100 -105.480 -116.028
```

To give a sense of the efficiency improvements of Rcpp vs. base R:

```
# Base R solution
f2 = function(Deposit, Interest) {
  Balance <- c(0, rep(NA, length(Deposit)))
  for (i in 2:length(Balance)) {
    Balance[i] = (Balance[i-1] + Deposit[i-1]) * (1+Interest[i-1])
  }
  return(Balance[-1])
}

set.seed(144)
Deposit <- runif(1000000, -1, 2)
Interest = runif(1000000, 0, 0.05)
system.time(getBalance(Deposit, Interest))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   0.008   0.000   0.008 
system.time(f2(Deposit, Interest))
#    user  system elapsed 
#   4.701   0.008   4.730
```

Answer (score 1):

Not enough rep to comment yet:

Can you give an indication of what data you have at each point/ when you wish to update? Do you wish to calculate, say, balance_after_interest(t) based on interest, balance(t-1) and deposits(t)?

Comment: I have the whole first data.table dtCash (as given in my example) with Deposit, Balance and Interest for all periods. I would like to calculate the column BalanceWithInterest in a data.table kind of way.

Comment: This seems off: Shouldn't you have balance=210 in the second instance, for example?

Comment: There are no interest calculations done whatsoever. Just deposits and withdrawals. I do know the interest rates that I want to apply, but missing any sort of calculation. Is that clearer?

Comment: I'm sorry, can you break it down a little more? How do you get 212.1 if you're not adding the previous interest? It seems like you should have 

Balance=c(100,210,... and so on)

Comment: All I have is this data.table dtCash <- data.table(
  Deposit = c(100, 100, -300, 0), 
  Balance = c(100, 200, -100, -100),
  Interest=c(0.1, 0.01, 0.2, 0.1)
) 
and I would like to get the result BalanceWithInterest = c(110, 212.1, -105.48, -116.028). That really is my question how to get to that.

Answer (score 1):

A somewhat messy answer:

```
library(data.table)

dtCash <- data.table(
  Deposit = c(100, 100, -300, 0), 
  Balance = c(100, 200, -100, -100),
  Interest=c(0.1, 0.01, 0.2, 0.1)
)
# Add row for t = 0
dtCash <- rbind(rep(0, ncol(dtCash)), dtCash)
# Add "dummy" column for interest-accrued balance
dtCash$Balance.1 <- c(0, rep(NA, nrow(dtCash)-1))

for ( i in seq(nrow(dtCash))[-1] ) {
    dtCash$Balance.1[i] <- (dtCash$Balance.1[i - 1] + dtCash$Deposit[i]) *
                              (1 + dtCash$Interest[i])
}

dtCash
#    Deposit Balance Interest Balance.1
# 1:       0       0     0.00     0.000
# 2:     100     100     0.10   110.000
# 3:     100     200     0.01   212.100
# 4:    -300    -100     0.20  -105.480
# 5:       0    -100     0.10  -116.028
```

Is this what you mean? This isn't super efficient, but it does give you what you are looking for. With some clever re-parameterisation you might be about to work around the explicit loop.

Also, if your problem size is small, you could just as well use `data.frame` rather than `data.table`. In this case, the notation would be identical. (And in this case, there is no advantage from using `data.table`.)

Comment: Thanks for the answer. That is what I meant.  I was hoping not to use an explicit loop and that someone could point out the "clever re-parameterisation" as I am failing to do this.

Comment: if you're going to loop through a `data.table`, you probably want to use `set`

Comment: @eddi, could you explain how you would use that in this example?

Comment: @WolfgangWu smth like this `set(dtCash, i, 4, dtCash$Balance.1[i-1] + ...)`

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to pull out the data, work it out with lapply(), and update it. I don't think there's any vector way to do it:

```
interest<-dtCash[,Interest]
balance<-dtCash[,Balance]
lapply(1:(length(interest)-1), # leave the last entry - nothing to add it to
       function(x)
         {balance[x+1]<<-balance[x+1]+balance[x]*interest[x]} # remember the double arrow
       )                                                      # because you're in a function

dtCash[,rollBal:=balance]

Deposit Balance Interest rollBal
1:     100     100     0.10  100.00
2:     100     200     0.01  220.00
3:    -300    -100     0.20  -95.70
4:       0    -100     0.10 -138.72
```